# Divide a set variable between a group of UISliders

Tags: xcode, dynamic, linker, swift, uislider

I'm having trouble getting UISliders to interact with each other, and don't have a good way to describe what I'm after; but here goes.

Suppose you are creating a role playing character and have 100 attribute points to spend.  You can divide the point into stats for Strength, Speed, Intelligence, Defense, and Luck.  So the attribute points available is my variable and the stats are my sliders.

If I put the strength slider to 80, then I shouldn't be able to slide any other slider past 20.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to dynamically set the UISlider maximum value based off the slider.value of the other sliders and the remaining value of the original variable.

This is a swift project, and that's where I'm having the most difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an array of sliders (you can do this as an outlet collection or set it up in your `viewDidLoad` method), then connect each slider to the `sliderChanged` method below.

`sliderChanged` calculates how much of the combined maximum has been used by all the sliders *except* the one currently moving, and then limits the currently moving slider to whatever's left over.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let combinedMaximum: Float = 100
    @IBOutlet var sliders: [UISlider]!

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let totalUsed = sliders.reduce(0) { (subtotal: Float, slider: UISlider) in
            if slider != sender {
                return subtotal + slider.value
            }
            return subtotal
        }
        let remainder = combinedMaximum - totalUsed
        if sender.value > remainder {
            sender.value = remainder
        }
    }

    // etc...   
}
```